# Alternate values of high pass filter isn't working, even though gain, phase & transient response is almost same

Tags: gain, high-pass-filter, hum

I'm trying to design a high pass filter to remove the humming noise (around 50-60Hz.) If I use alternate values, it's not working.

It's the recommended value from a YouTube video (470pF, 5.6Mohm.). Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzKQv5-UnAU&t=178s

Here the noise is reduced by 10dB (noise=75dB)

[image]

We used these values (1kohm, 2.2uF) because of the smaller size and availability but this filter isn't reducing the hum noise at all. Current noise = 85dB (same as without the filter)

[image]

Overall gain, phase & transient response are almost the same. I don't know whether we need to choose the capacitor value based on its reactance or not as it's a standard formula.

Update on 30-Nov-23:

1. SCU(6-layer): We've one SCU board that has a. microphone input(from ECU connector) -> b. analog switch(audio to display & speaker) -> c. a bandpass filter(reject noise outside the audio range).we're connecting the bandpass filter output to another board.
2. Audio Amp(2-layer): The audio input from the SCU board(via twisted cable) is going to codec ->audio amplifiers-> speakers.

We were hearing constant hissing noise so introduced a highpass filter with a cut-off frequency of around 80Hz(since human voice starts from 85Hz). The noise reduced with 5Meg & 470pF but it didn't happen with other RC filter values so was curious to understand.

We understood that all the noises are from the ground only(especially due to poor ground connection in the 2-layer board) but we don't have enough knowledge to understand the ground bounce/loops(If it was digital then we could have visualized something but with analog, it's damn difficult).

If you guys can guide us on this then it'd be very helpful.

Comment: You need to show what the input and output connects to and describe what each of those things is powered by. Reason: you've probably introduced a ground/earth loop with the lower value resistor.

Comment: what is the source? the new circuit has a MUCH lower input impedance and unless the source impedance is <1k you will have problems. I suspect that there is a very good reason for the high impedance of the old circuit.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka & danmcb, I've updated the question with the source & connection. 
It'll be very helpful if you could help me in reducing the hissing/humming noise that's arising due to poor ground connection.

Comment: Your highpass filter is very simple so it reduces 60Hz only about 4dB which is a very small reduction. The highpass filter passes the high frequency hiss probably caused by the preamp circuit.

Comment: @Audioguru, thanks for the reply. I'm designing a 2nd order filter which is having better slew rate & better reduction at 60hz(about -10dB) but it's taking time to source the components. From your POV, preamp means bandpass filter?

Comment: You posted no complete schematic so I am guessing that the input is the microphone. If the mic connects to the mic preamp through an unshielded audio cable then the cable is an antenna for the electricity hum that is all around. I have made hundreds or thousands of audio systems with a frequency response down to 20Hz with no hum and no hiss. Your simple twisted pair cable also picks up hum and is used with no-bass telephones.